# Live server (five server) in VS Code the web page favicon not change and it used existing web page favion when I start live server

Tags: favicon, liveserver

Live server (five server) in VS Code the web page favicon not change and it used existing web page favion when i start live server. I try not only to think the existing favicon remove it will show current file favicon.

Existing file favicon is another folder and current file is another folder and also i am not use favicon in current file but when i run the current file it show existing file favicon specifically when start live server click go live this problem occur but without using live server. Run in VS Code this problem not occur.